# How to make xubuntu boot faster on old computer?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

I recently reinstalled my computer with xubuntu to 16.10 with hopes to get faster boot again, but boot still takes about two minutes. What settings do i change to prevent already checked checks and/or loading support for hardware i dont have present? My pc is old Pentium 4 at 3Ghz with 80GB hdd and 3GB ram. Wired internet, no wireless nonsense. Dualboot with Win XP.

edit: cant paste it, too big, so i saved it to text file [here](http://nomohakon.sweb.cz/dmesg.txt).

Comment: Please add the dmesg output to your post so we may see what's taking so much time.  Use the code tags on the advanced posting.

Comment: i tried, but apparently im too dumb, so, how do i get the log?

Comment: Start a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-t) and type dmesg.  Then cut and paste the output into your question.  Using the code tags (advanced editing?)  will put it into a scrollable box so it's easier to read.

Comment: added the dmesg, sorry it took so long.

Comment: I see 40 seconds, with a big chunk looking like IPV6 setup -- do you really mean to use IPV6?